# MySQL: How to sort when using concat in group_concat?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I need to sort `date` in `concat` within `group_concat` while my query is running fine:

```
 SELECT 
    report.`Name`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
      CONCAT(
        "[",
      DATE(report.Date) --(not working) order by DATE(report.Date)  ,
        ',',
      report.ProductPrice --(not working) order by DATE(report.ProductPrice) ,
        "]"
      ) 
    ) AS ProductPrice  
  FROM report
 GROUP BY report.Name ;
```

[image]

Comment: when i use concat then order by stops working gives error

Comment: `CONCAT` is a function, you can't use clauses in functions (except some window functions). You have to do the ordering OUTSIDE of the `CONCAT()` function. Furthermore, you can not have more than one `ORDER BY` clause in a `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use it in `group_concat`, not `concat`:

```
group_concat(
  concat('[', date(report.Date), ',', report.ProductPrice, ']') 
  order by date(report.Date) desc
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to provide the `ORDER BY` clauses as arguments to [CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), which does not support that (mainly because it wouldn't make sense to sort a single value). The signature for [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) shows that's where you have to put them:

```
GROUP_CONCAT([DISTINCT] expr [,expr ...]
             [ORDER BY {unsigned_integer | col_name | expr}
                 [ASC | DESC] [,col_name ...]]
             [SEPARATOR str_val])
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work

```
 SELECT report.`Name`,GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("[",DATE(report.Date) --(NOT working),',',report.ProductPrice --(NOT working)),"]") ORDER BY DATE(report.ProductPrice ) AS ProductPrice  
  FROM report
 GROUP BY report.Name ;
```